# Does .NET 3.5 allow to use the new features of Windows 7?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-7

Some of the applications running on Windows 7 (Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, in example) use the icon they present in the task bar to show a little progress bar. Is it possible to use that feature using the .NET Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the Windows API Code Pack

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

This assembly provides access to Windows specific features like the tool bar.  It allows for just the scenario you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/)

Answer (score 0):

Since the new taskbar APIs can be accessed from C or C++ using Win32 API calls and COM, you can access them from any version of .NET by calling into the C APIs. Some examples can be found in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx). See also the resources linked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee624070.aspx).